# Is an http.Agent employed in a nodejs web server which only serves requests?

Tags: node.js, sockets, http

Creating a new http.Agent seems useful for a web server because I'd be able to control how many sockets to allot, whether to keep unused sockets pooled (the `keepAlive` flag), etc...

That being said, I see no way to pass a custom agent into the creation of a new server.  Is it that I need to edit `http.globalAgent`?

In the v7.3.0 nodejs docs it says:

> The default http.globalAgent that is used by **http.request**()...

This also makes me wonder how this would even work when issuing an `http.request`.  As in, will the server it's calling (any server) recognize that it should only allot x number of sockets, and why should the client be the one determining such things in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [read the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

> **`http.request(options[, callback])`**
>
> - `options` [Object]
>
>   •••
>
>   - `agent` [http.Agent] | [Boolean] Controls Agent behavior. Possible values:
>
>     - `undefined` (default): use `http.globalAgent` for this host and port.
>     - *Agent object*: explicitly use the passed in Agent.
>     - `false`: causes a new Agent with default values to be used.
>   - `createConnection` [Function] A function that produces a socket/stream to use for the request when the agent option is not used. This can be used to avoid creating a custom Agent class just to override the default createConnection function. See `agent.createConnection()` for more details.
>   - `timeout` [Integer]: A number specifying the socket timeout in milliseconds. This will set the timeout before the socket is connected.
> - `callback` [Function]
>
> Returns:

As far as your other question: think of a socket as **a** pipe connecting two computers. If you only have a single socket open, you can only make a single request at a time; if you have *n* sockets open, you can make *n* requests **in parallel**.

Comment: Yah, it's much clearer now: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/10715  ;)  Thank you for reminding me to take another look at the docs.  Makes sense now.